# How to get the zoom event of a C# chart

Tags: c#, winforms, events, charts, zooming

I have a chart (the standard chart that comes with win-forms visual studio) that I've set up zooming on. Every time this chart is zoomed I would like to run a function, however I cannot find an event that is triggered on zoom. I looked though the list of events and the only one that I thought may work was "AxisViewChanged", however this is triggered on many changes and I don't know how to single out just the zoom changes. Is there some zoom event I'm missing? or does this just not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
    double oldSelStart = -1;
    double oldSelEnd = -1;
    private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
    {
        double newSelStart = chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].CursorX.SelectionStart;
        double newSelEnd = chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].CursorX.SelectionEnd;
        const double TOLERANCE = 0.1;

        if (Math.Abs(oldSelEnd - newSelEnd) > TOLERANCE || Math.Abs(newSelStart - oldSelStart) > TOLERANCE)
        {
            oldSelStart = newSelStart;
            oldSelEnd = newSelEnd;

            //Zoom has actually changed do your stuff
        }
    }
```

Basically you remember your old zoom ranges and handle AxisViewChanged yourself and determine if the zoom has actually changed

Comment: Mostly seems to work, however when I use the "-" to zoom out I get NaN for start and end values (both X & Y) I tried changing all NaN to Zeros, however since I get NaN for both cursorX and CursorY, I only get "Zoomed" for the first click of the "-" (Second click would be other axis). I hope this made sense.. please ask if there is anything I need to clarify.

Comment: Basically there is no Zoom Event you will have to inspect/record all things that change when you zoom and extend the above code

Comment: Got it working Instead of tracking CursorX.SelectionStart and End I'm tracking AxisX.ScaleView.Size && AxisX.ScaleView.IsZoomed. seems to work for my purposes. Thanks =)